# How to read csv files in spyder(python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, file-io, spyder

I have written this code

```
import csv as csv 
import numpy as np

csv_file_object=
csv.reader(open('C:\Users\hostname\Desktop\spyder\train.csv', 'rb'))

header = csv_file_object.next()
data=[]

for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
data = np.array(data)
```

but Error ([Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:) appears.

Comment: Since you are under Windows, try changing the backward slashes to forward slashes in the file path 'C:/Users/hostname/Desktop/spyder/train.csv'.

Comment: If I change to forward slash then this error shows up [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/hostname/Desktop/train.csv'

Comment: Can you maybe double-check your file path and make sure that the file indeed exists at 'C:/Users/hostname/Desktop/train.csv' (note that you had C:/Users/hostname/Desktop/spyder/train.csv before)? What happens if you put the train.csv in the same folder as your script and load it with `csv.reader(open('train.csv', 'rb'))`?

Comment: @Pold Linux normally uses forward slashes for paths. It's Windows that uses backslashes. Backslashes in a Linux path typically indicate escaped characters such as single quotes and spaces in file names (which you should never have btw.)

Comment: @user280271 You're missing a closing parenthesis in this line `csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('C:\Users\hostname\Desktop\spyder\train.csv', 'rb')`

Comment: @jDo Forward slashes for file paths in python work fine under Linux and Windows; backslashes are also interpreted as escape characters under Windows. Therefore, user280271 can change the path using forward slashes or escape the backslashes with '\\', for example 'C:\\Users\\train.csv'.

Comment: @Pold Cool cool. I've never used python in windows and never had a reason for writing backslashes in paths (except for escaping), but good to know that it works either way.

Comment: @jDo I have closed the parenthesis but the error remains the same .

Comment: Can you update the code in your example too?

Comment: 'C:/Users/hostname/Desktop/train.csv' != "C:\Users\hostname\Desktop\spyder\train.csv' 
Where's "spyder" in path 1? You have the same file in two locations? 
Try 'C:/Users/hostname/Desktop/spyder/train.csv' and if it doesn't work, do as python suggests and change `mode ('rb')` - maybe just to `'r'` instead of `'rb'`

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest using numpy `genfromtxt`

```
import numpy as np
np.genfromtxt('C:\Users\hostname\Desktop\spyder\train.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=None)
```

You'll have to adjust the `delimiter` and `dtype` parameters based on your csv file.